# AS3 External SWF Full Screen Button

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Right now in my project I have a main SWF that loads an external SWF that contains a youtube chromeless player. My issue right now is that the main+loaded swf are embedded in HTML and there is an effect on the site that moves the flash. I have the video controls in html/javascript but since I can't externally call fullscreen unless its a flash button the controls have a "hole" in the bar to allow a button in flash to poke through for fullscreen. Issue is that when the flash moves, so does the fullscreen button.

Basically can a separate embedded flash swf just act as a fullscreen button for another embedded flash object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having one SWF invoke another one to go fullscreen is unfortunately not possible for security reasons, even if you use LocalConnection.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve isn't possible. I recommend that you look into solutions that involve dealing with the movement of the Flash element on your page and abandoning your current idea.